# Is it possible to add a password to generated PDF in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf-generation

I found how to add a password while you are writing the data into the disk,

```
pdfDocument.write(to: encryptedFileURL, withOptions: [PDFDocumentWriteOption.userPasswordOption : "pwd",
PDFDocumentWriteOption.ownerPasswordOption : "pwd"])
```

but in my case, I'm generating the PDF file differently. I'm generating it from data and directly in the MailComposer convert and send it like:

```
if let pdfData = printPageRenderer.drawPDFUsingPrintPageRenderer(printPageRenderer: printPageRenderer) {
    mailComposer.addAttachmentData(pdfData as Data, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: "PDF")
}
```

But I cannot find a way how can I add a password to my PDF file if I'm not saving the file on my FileManager and I'm not using PDFKit.
Are there any options to do that? It would be great to know that. Any tips or help are appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

I assume you use UIGraphicsPDFRenderer in iOS to obtain the PDF data.

When initializing  UIGraphicsPDFRenderer, you may have to give an UIGraphicsPDFRendererFormat.

In this UIGraphicsPDFRendererFormat, you can set format.documentInfo.
This documentInfo has

```
  const CFStringRef kCGPDFContextUserPassword 
  const CFStringRef kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword;
```

Hopefully, you can get what you like.

Comment: Really bad answer without any explanation